# Horizontal-form with formtastic and bootstrap 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I can't make the elements to take the right html classes so that they are displayed properly.

I'm using

- rails 4.2.0
- formtastic 3.1.3
- formtastic-bootstrap 3.1.0
- bootstrap-sass 3.3.3

Looking at the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) the html should look like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So far I could add the class to the form, but I wasn't able to make the label and the input wrapper to have the right `col-sm-XX` classes.

I'm totally new to formtastic and bootstrap... How could I generate the right html?